# Adding to complex DQL Query

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, dql

Hello I have this query witch works fine

```
SELECT y,
        CASE WHEN (v IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE SUM(v.viewCount) END AS HIDDEN sumviewcount
        FROM YTScraperBundle:YouTubeVideo y
        LEFT JOIN y.allViews WITH v.firstFetch BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate
        GROUP BY y ORDER BY sumviewcount DESC
```

This is the SQL that is generated by the DQL

```
SELECT y0_.id AS id0, y0_.video_id AS video_id1, y0_.name AS name2, y0_.type AS type3, y0_.link AS
link4, y0_.first_fetch AS first_fetch5, y0_.last_fetch AS last_fetch6, CASE WHEN (v1_.id IS NULL) 
THEN 0 ELSE SUM(v1_.viewCount) END AS sclr7 FROM youtubevideo y0_ LEFT JOIN views v1_ ON y0_.id 
v1_.youtubevideo_id AND (v1_.first_fetch BETWEEN ? AND ?) GROUP BY y0_.id, y0_.video_id, y0_.name, 
y0_.type, y0_.link, y0_.first_fetch, y0_.last_fetch ORDER BY sclr7 DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

I need to add a upper LIKE clause, that sorts this first. The above query works fine, but it runs on all YouTubeVideo's y, if I want it to run on just some of the videos where name has a specifik LIKE value, I would add an AND clause after the LEFT JOIN.

But I dont know where to add it, if I add it after the:

```
BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate
```

Like this:

```
BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate AND y.name LIKE '%somevalue%'
```

The SQL renders like this:

```
LEFT JOIN views v1_ ON y0_.id 
v1_.youtubevideo_id AND (v1_.first_fetch BETWEEN ? AND ? AND y.name LIKE '%somevalue%')
```

The clause I am adding should not be inside the between paranthesis. It shouldn't it be outside?

Anyway how can I get around the BETWEEN statment? can I make it a:

```
...MyComparison AND BETWEEN...
```

?

Answer (score 0):

try below where clause

```
  Where '2014-10-01'< Date_Column and '2014-11-01'>Date_column and name like '%abc%'
```